# Shared server php sessions in /tmp

Tags: php, session

I have a client that is own a shared host the uses php sessions. The session save path is /tmp by default. They are having random logouts.

Could this be caused by any/all of these?

1. Garbage collection by other user on the server?
2. Someone clearing out /tmp files (User or cron). This seems unlikely as the host I am using is pretty well known

I can change the session save path to a folder under their control. Do you think this would be the best solution? I know shared hosts sessions are insecure as anyone can read them (and I think even write to them via nobody/apache user)

Comment: Yes, I would go for storing sessions in a private directory or even in the [database](http://shiflett.org/articles/storing-sessions-in-a-database)

Comment: Do you think both 1 and 2 could be happening?

Comment: Hard to tell, is very likely that somehow the session file is being deleted, you can try and ask the support team of your hosting company... PS: Are you sure that there is no timeout? This would explain also the "sudden" logout...

Comment: I have an ajax keep alive that runs every 5 minutes to keep the session active in case they leave their application open without clicking anything. This should prevent the session from expiring. I am still following up with host but they are pretty slow and getting back to me.

Comment: What if you share the session using Memcache and store the session variables on other servers?
Then you can control the files on a different server, your own dir, etc.
Just an idea

Comment: I do use memcached on one of my servers, but this is a client's server with limited access. What I am recommending to them is to private a folder in their home directory and store sessions there. This way no one else will be able to delete sessions.